# Displaying links in Java components

Tags: java, html, swing, hyperlink

I want to display a list of links in a java component, doesn't matter what component it is.
By links I mean URLs of some sites.
Those links can be clicked and doing so opens chosen URL in the default web browser for example google chrome / firefox ( I don't want to display web pages in java, only links ).

I already know how to display single link, but I am having problems with display a list of links. I tried to do it like this :

```
 public void appendTextToJEditorPane(String text) {

    try {
        Document doc = jEditorPane1.getDocument();
        String newLine = "\n";

        String url = "<html><a href=" + text + ">" + text + "<//a><//html>.";

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), url, null);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), newLine, null);

    } catch (BadLocationException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }


}

    appendTextToJEditorPane("http://google.pl");
    appendTextToJEditorPane("http://wp.pl");
    appendTextToJEditorPane("http://onet.pl");
```

but it doesn't work due to problems with "/" in the html closing tag. And I get plain text in JEditorPane. How to append links properly?

Comment: Doesn't really matter - can be JTextPane, JTextArea, JEditorPane, List..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html in JLabel component. That means you can use links via a-href also.

```
label.setText("<html><a href="your-link">link</a></html>.")
```

Comment: Well this works for a single link. For instance I do somthing like this :

String url = "http://google.com";
jEditorPane1.setText("<html><a href=" + url + ">" + url + "</a> </html>.");
but how to append more links?

Comment: I talked about JLabel not JEditorPane but it seems works for other components also. Solution: include your links between <html> tags. in one setText method. Good approach in using StringBuilder to construct your html text with links.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make an HTML of links and open this page in JEditorPane, will help you to code less and achieve your requirement.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Swing, it is possible to put HTML formatted text on a component. So making your text <html><a href="...">...</a></html> should be enough.
Otherwise, you'll have to implement an ActionListener that opens the browser. You can do this with the [Desktop.browse(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) method.

Comment: Thanks.That is correct, but I'm having problems with getting desktop supported in newest linux ubuntu version. Method Desktop.isSupported() returs false and I don't know how to fix it, because I am not an expert in linux. Any ideas maybe?

Comment: I don't, but someone else might. It sounds like good material for another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your component clickable you can open the browser from within your program with the URL. See java.lang.Desktop, the browse method specifically.

Comment: How to make a component clickable? What property is responsible for that?

Comment: You add a MouseListener to your component or ActionListener should it be a button, and when the listener is invoked with the event you open the browser.

Comment: I saw from your other answers that you had problem with the Desktop support. Strange. It is possible to use java.lang.Process to invoke your browser directly, but I don't see why at this point. I assume you are running with a graphical display.